# Error when attempting to compute a triple integral

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I am trying to do a triple integration, but I'm getting an error message that I don't understand.

```
clear all;
%%%==== just some parameters ========== 
a=4; 
la1=1/(pi*500^2); la2= la1*5;
p1=25; p2=p1/25;
sgma2=10^(-11);
index=1;
g=2./a;
syms r u1 u2  u3
powe= -2 
seta= 10^powe;
q=pi.*(la1.*p1.^(2./a)+la2.*p2.^(2./a));
 %%%==== parameters -- end ==========    

yi = @(u3,u2,u1) exp(-u3.*(1+2.*...
      (  pi./4 - atan(10.*(u3.^2./u1.^2 + u3.^2./u2.^2 + 1).^(1./2))./2    )./...
      (  (( (u3./u1).^(a./2) + (u3./u2).^(a./2) + 1    ).^(2./a)).*seta.^(-2./a)))).*...
                exp(-sgma2.*q.^(-a./2).* seta.*u3.^(a./2)./...
        ((( (u3./u1).^(a./2) + (u3./u2).^(a./2) + 1    ).^(2./a)).^(a./2))  );      

          maxF2 =@(u2) u2; 
          maxF3 =@(u3) u3;
         out2 = integral3(yi, 0, Inf , 0,  maxF3 , 0, maxF2)
```

As you see, `u3` is `[0, Inf]`, `u2` is `[0, u3]`, `u1` is `[0, u2]`. The error messages I get are as follows:

```
Error using @(u2)u2
Too many input arguments.

Error in integral3>@(y)ZMAXXY(x(1)*ones(size(y)),y) (line 142)
            @(y)ZMAXXY(x(1)*ones(size(y)),y), ...

Error in integral2Calc>integral2t/tensor (line 191)
        top = YMAX(x);

Error in integral2Calc>integral2t (line 56)
[Qsub,esub] = tensor(thetaL,thetaR,phiB,phiT);

Error in integral2Calc (line 10)
    [q,errbnd] = integral2t(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,optionstruct);

Error in integral3/innerintegral (line 138)
        Q1 = integral2Calc( ...

Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
                fx = FUN(t);

Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 133)
            [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);

Error in integralCalc (line 84)
        [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AToInfInvTransform,interval);

Error in integral3 (line 122)
    Q = integralCalc(@innerintegral,xmin,xmax,integralOptions);

Error in ref7_equ11n3 (line 33)
       out2 = integral3(yi, 0, Inf , 0,  maxF3 , 0, maxF2)
```

What's the meaning of

```
Error using @(u2)u2 Too many input arguments.
```

If I change the range of `u2` and `u3` to real number (e.g. `out2 = integral3(yi, 0, Inf , 0, 1000 , 0, 1000)` ), then it works: `out2` will be a real number. What am I doing wrong?

I think I got it. The answer is out2 = integral3(yi, 0, Inf , 0,  @(u3) u3 , 0, @(u3,u2) u2). But I dont know why. anyone got some idea?  THanks

Comment: `integral3` is a numeric function, it can not deal with symbolics. For the integral of symbolic functions try `int` from the symbolics toolbox (`doc symbolic/int` to open documentation)

Comment: @Daniel  Thanks for your answer. I am doing numerical integration, not symbolic calculation. I expect the final output of out2 is a number.

Comment: I think I got it. The answer is out2 = integral3(yi, 0, Inf , 0,  @(u3) u3 , 0, @(u3,u2) u2). But I dont know why. anyone got some idea?  THanks

Comment: you have messed up numerical and symbolical computations

Comment: @sunson29: I was irritated by the symbolic variables, but they are unused. Did not realize it when writing my original comment. Could you give us a mathematical definition of the integral you are trying to implement? It might be that your latest code is correct, but I'm not sure what you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a complete answer, regarding your last code line:

```
out2 = integral3(yi, 0, Inf , 0, @(u3) u3 , 0, @(u3,u2) u2)
```

I am not sure what you wanted to implement, but you have implemented this formula:

[image]
[edit](http://www.codecogs.com/eqnedit.php?latex=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7Binf%7D&space;%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7Bu_3%7D&space;%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7Bu_2%7D&space;f(u_3,u_2,u_1)&space;%5Cfrac%7B%5Cmathrm%7Bd%7D&space;%7D%7B%5Cmathrm%7Bd%7D&space;u_1%7D&space;%5Cfrac%7B%5Cmathrm%7Bd%7D&space;%7D%7B%5Cmathrm%7Bd%7D&space;u_2%7D&space;%5Cfrac%7B%5Cmathrm%7Bd%7D&space;%7D%7B%5Cmathrm%7Bd%7D&space;u_3%7D)

Maybe you can check if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks alot! But do you know why '@(u3,u2) u2' ? not just u2? I mean why u1 must be a function of both u3 and u2. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the inner-most integral. The upper bound is `u2` but any term of `u2` and `u3` would be possible. That`s why a function handle with two inputs is expected.